# Reading shapefile in R with shapefile function?

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, rgdal

I want to read a shapefile(polyline) into R, using rgdal and raster packages.

The code looks like:

```
d<-file("/Volumes/Environment_layers/original/WaterRoad/Road.shp")
o<-shapefile(d)
```

but I got a warning:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"file"’
```

I am new in using R dealing with spatial layers.

Comment: Does this related post help?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/19064

Comment: @Aaron *NOT* a duplicate. User here has mistakenly called `file` on the path and passed a `file` object (hence the error). I suspect this might be a pythonic paradigm from someone used to python. Either way, its a specific error that other people might encounter and so is worth having as a question as my explanation details the solution.

Comment: @Spacedman Reopened, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
d <- file("/Volumes/Environment_layers/original/WaterRoad/Road.shp")
```

which is calling `file` on the path. This opens the file for reading by R's general reading and writing routines. The `shapefile` function handles all this so you don't pass it a `file` object, you pass it the path as a string.

This should work:

```
d <- "/Volumes/Environment_layers/original/WaterRoad/Road.shp"
o <- shapefile(d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! yes it works well for me. Also I tried another way, using: